# Difference between hadoop and google analytics

Tags: hadoop, google-analytics, bigdata, data-integration

Helly guys,

I am new to hadoop and everything around big data.
while my research about social media data integration with big data i found a lot about hadoop.

But I know there is google analytics too, if i want to observe social media and get some statistics.

So, why are so many companies using hadoop instead of google analytics?
What is the difference between those two?

Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I will try and answer this as good as possible, as it's a strange question :)

The reason I say it's strange is they are not really related and trying to find a co-relation to compare is tricky.

GA - Typically used to track web behavior. Provides a nice UI and is typically digestible by non-technical people (marketing etc) to find insights.

Hadoop - Hadoop at its core is a file system (think of a very large hard-drive), it stores data in a distributed fashion (on n number of servers). It's claim to fame is map/reduce and the plethora of applications like Hive or Pig to analyze data sitting in Hadoop.

A better comparison to the products you mentioned would be something like:

1. Why would I use Google Analytics vs Comscore? (web analytics)
2. Why would I use Hadoop vs Postgres? (data storage and data analyses)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Now I can understand the difference between these products. :) This will help a lot!